# Structure a query to only display today's event after a certain time of day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that pulls homework assignments for students.  I want to always display everything less than or equal to today's date, which is fine and done, but how can I add a stipulation in either PHP or MySQL that displays today's event after 8:30am, while still displaying anything prior to today all the time.

Trying to prevent students from seeing their homework before they get to school.

```
        //Get & Display the Homework
    $getTopics = mysql_query("SELECT topicId, categoryId, topicName, assignmentDate FROM forumTopics WHERE categoryId = '".$forumId."' AND hidden = '0' and assignmentDate <= '".$today."' ORDER BY createdDate DESC") or die("Cannot get forum topics: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: The `mysql` extension is deprecated. Do not use it.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL is:

```
SELECT topicId, categoryId, topicName, assignmentDate
FROM forumTopics
WHERE categoryId = '".$forumId."' AND hidden = '0' and assignmentDate <= '".$today."'
ORDER BY createdDate DESC;
```

To make this show today only after 8:30 a.m.:

```
SELECT topicId, categoryId, topicName, assignmentDate
FROM forumTopics
WHERE categoryId = '".$forumId."' AND hidden = '0' and
      (assignmentDate < '".$today."' or assigmentDate = '".$today."' and time('".today."') >= '08:30:00'
ORDER BY createdDate DESC;
```

This is assuming that your variable `$today` has both the date and time.  Otherwise, just use `now()` and/or `CURDATE()` and/or `CURTIME()`.